# Random sum of elements in an array equals to y - ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Need to create an array whose sum should be equal to expected value.

```
 inp = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
 sum = 200
```

output:

```
out = [10,10,9,1,3,3,3,7,.....]  whose sum should be 200
or
out = [10,7,3,....]              Repeated values can be used
or
out = [2,3,4,9,2,....]
```

I tried as,

```
arr = [5,10,15,20,30]
ee = []
max = 200
while (ee.sum < max) do
  ee << arr.sample(1).first
end

ee.pop(2)
val = max - ee.sum
pair = arr.uniq.combination(2).detect { |a, b| a + b == val }
ee << pair
ee.flatten
```

Is there any effective way to do it.

Comment: This is a good question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @sagarpandya82,  I have added it

Comment: @falsetru, this is not a duplicate question.
Here repeated values can be used in output, which is not there in any of the question. Remove the word duplicate from this question.

Answer (score 2):

```
inp = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
sum = 20

inp.length.downto(1).flat_map do |i|
  inp.combination(i).to_a # take all subarrays of length `i`
end.select do |a| 
  a.inject(:+) == sum     # select only those summing to `sum`
end
```

One might take a `random` element of resulting array.

```
result = inp.length.downto(1).flat_map do |i|
  inp.combination(i).to_a # take all subarrays of length `i`
end.select do |a| 
  a.inject(:+) == sum     # select only those summing to `sum`
end
puts result.length
#⇒ 31
puts result.sample
#⇒ [2, 4, 5, 9]
puts result.sample
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, 6, 8]
...
```

Please note, that this approach is not efficient for long-length inputs. As well, if any original array’s member might be taken many times, [`combination`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) above should be changed to [`permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation), but this solution is too ineffective to be used with `permutation`.

Comment: Thanks, one small think, it should work even if the target is 2000
Repeated elements in an array can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer of this question in the following link:

[Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[])
 s = partial.inject 0, :+
 #check if the partial sum is equals to target
 puts "sum(#{partial})=#{target}" if s == target
 return if s >= target  #if we reach the number why bother to continue
 (0..(numbers.length - 1)).each do |i|
   n = numbers[i]
   remaining = numbers.drop(i+1)
   subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])
 end
end

subset_sum([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],20)
```

Comment: Thanks, one small think, it should work even if the target is 2000
Repeated elements in an array can be used.